# CriteriaBuilder. How to represent a JOIN of one table by two foreign keys with OR condition through CriteriaBuilder?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I have, for example, two tables:
Table1:

- id
- name

Table2:

- id
- title
- parent_id (FK to table1)
- child_id (FK to table1)

How to repsent a query like this through CriteriaBuilder:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON (t2.parent_id = t1.id OR t2.child_id = t1.id)
WHERE t2.title = {title}
```

I tried this code, but it didn't help. First condition overwrites the second one

```
Root<Table1> table1 = cq.from(Table1.class);
Join<Table1, Table2> table2 = table2.join(Table1_.parent, JoinType.LEFT);
table2.on(cb.or(cd.equal(table2.get(Table2_.id), Table1_.parent.id), cd.equal(table2.get(Table2_.id), Table1_.child.id));
...
```

Comment: I worked on it long back, but my experience says you would need to Join same table twice. So that both conditions can be matched.

Comment: Your code looks fine AFAICT. I have no idea what you mean by "overwrites the second one". Maybe you are calling `table2.on(..)` somewhere else afterwards?